# Integrity error,element can't be added

Tags: django

Something went wrong when i decided to bind my model to a user,database).  I guess something is wrong with my model. Any help would be much appreciated.

models.py

```
class Word(models.Model):
  name=models.CharField(max_length=100,unique=True)
  translation=models.CharField(max_length=255)
  created_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
  times_used=models.IntegerField(default=0,editable=False)
  user=models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='created_by',null=False)
```

When i try to create an element,this message appears:

```
 IntegrityError at /words/
 NOT NULL constraint failed: words_word.user_id
```

views.py:

```
class Create_Word(generic.CreateView):
    model=Word
    fields=['name','translation',]
    template_name = "words/list_all.html"
```

Comment: Show us the code where you create Word.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev It's just a generic view. Added it to the description

Comment: Check the template, there must be a for statement on it { for word in words... }

Comment: @NeoVe  it's been working fine,until i created a new ForeignKey

Comment: You should add required fields into `fields` array like: `fields=['name', 'translation', 'user']`

Comment: @ozgur I just don't need to specify the user,it should register user behind the scenes

Comment: Well, maybe that's the problem, is that FK about the user_id? Is there a 'published' post on it?

Comment: By looking at your code, there must be some post, obviously assigned to some user there

Comment: No, you should manually pass user object (probably `self.request.user`) somehow somewhere onto the form instance.

Comment: Clean your 'words' table on database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must explicitly assign the current user to the field, there is nothing like `auto_now_add` for `ForeignKey`.

```
class CreateWord(CreateView):
    model = Word
    fields=['name','translation',]
    template_name = "words/list_all.html"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        word = form.save(commit=False)
        word.user = self.request.user
        return super(CreateWord, self).form_valid(form)
```